# Detect when my Mac app is crashing, then go ahead and crash normally

Tags: macos, signals

Normally, when a Mac app gets a crashing signal such as `SIGSEGV` or `SIGILL`, the process stops and a few seconds later the OS somehow creates a crash report file and tells the user about it.  But if I intercept the signal with a `sigaction` handler, that normal behavior does not happen.  What I would like to do is detect when the crash is happening, do a little work using the few functions that are documented as safe to call in a signal handler, but then go ahead and crash in the normal way.  Is there a way to do that? I tried re-raising the signal within the signal handler, but that didn't do the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get pretty much the behavior I wanted by ending the signal handler like so, re-sending the signal with default handling:

```c
signal( inSignal, SIG_DFL );
pthread_kill( pthread_self(), inSignal );
usleep( 10000 ); /* give time for signal to happen */
```

Looking at [Apple's source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.250.1/stdlib/FreeBSD/abort.c.auto.html) for `abort()` help me figure this out.